# Passing jtextfield value from one class to another

Tags: java

i have question regarding how to pass value of the jextfield from one frame to the jtextfield in the second frame upon click on a button.

The example below, after inputting a value in the nett wage textfield, upon clicking the add button, the value will be passed on to the nett wage textfield of the second frame.

Frame 1. I tried to add actionlistener to my button to get text, but how do i set it in the second frame? Appreciate if anyone can offer some advice and help.

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame{
public Frame1() {

    JPanel guiPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel Nett = new JLabel("Nett Wage: ");
    final JTextField nettNameTextField = new JTextField(10);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");


    JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    labelGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 3, 3, 3);
    GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    fieldGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 3, 3, 3);
    GridBagConstraints titleGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;


    fields.add(Nett, labelGBC);
    fields.add(nettNameTextField, fieldGBC);


    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints addButtonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    addButtonGBC.insets = new Insets(40, 3, 3, 3);
    cancelButtonGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    buttons.add(addButton, addButtonGBC);


    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    guiPanel.add(fields, gbc);
    guiPanel.add(buttons, gbc);


    add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    /*addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String value = nettNameTextField.getText();

        }
    });*/
```

Frame 2. how do i go about setting the value in the textfield here?

```
public class Frame2 extends JFrame {
public Frame2() {


    JPanel guiPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());


    JLabel nett = new JLabel("Nett Wage: ");
    JTextField nettNameTextField = new JTextField(10);


    JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());


    GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    labelGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 3, 3, 3);
    GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    fieldGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 3, 3, 3);
    //GridBagConstraints titleGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;




    JPanel savingspanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints totallabelsGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    totallabelsGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 3, 3, 3);
    GridBagConstraints totalfieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    totalfieldGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 3, 3, 3);
    totalfieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    savingspanel.add(nett, labelGBC);
    savingspanel.add(nettNameTextField, fieldGBC);



    add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);                      
        }       
}                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If an instance of Frame2 exists before Frame1**

In `Frame1`, pass an instance of `Frame2` in, in either the constructor or in a mutator method.

```
public Frame1(Frame2 frame2)
{
    this.frame2 = frame2;
}
```

Then in `Frame2`, have a method that can update the value, something like `updateNetWage`.

```
public void updateNetWage(String value)
{
    nettNameTextField.setText(value);
}
```

In your `actionListener` function, you can then simply call:

```
frame2.updateNetWage(value);
```

**If an instance of Frame2 is not available**

You can define a one parameter constructor for `Frame2`, so you can create a new object with the value in it.

```
public Frame2(String netNameValue)
{
    nettNameTextField.setText(netNameValue);
}
```

Comment: Maybe he should not pass complete Frame1 reference to constructor. I would prefer that he let implement Frame1 an interface with a special get method and just pass this interface to Frame2 constructor.

Comment: If you just pass the interface, you're still passing the object. It's a good point, but in my mind it's a needless extension and will only make the code more complex for the sake of using one method a programmer can get in seconds.